# socat: How to do simple duplex communication with shell?

Tags: shell-script, shell, socat

I would like to create a TCP connection to a remote server with `socat`, where a client sends

1. an action for an image file (`"convert"`,  `"open"`, etc.)
2. the image (binary content) itself

Server will then process the image with given action.

My first idea has been to pass this text action type before the binary content:

```bash
# client
socat tcp:server:9999 -\
  < <(echo "open"; cat path/to/imgfile)

# server
socat tcp-listen:9999 - | {
  IFS= read -r action
  cat - > /tmp/imgfile
  # do process image file with action type ...
}
```

This seems to work for particular case, but is inflexible, e.g. when needing to pass multiple arguments. Also prepending text before binary content makes me think, the image file potentially could be damaged?

Hence I am trying to find a cleaner solution, passing both arguments one by one (here referred to as duplex communication):

[image]

My attempt so far, not being an expert on `socat`:

```bash
# client
socat\
  tcp:server:9999\
  system:'echo "open"; IFS= read -r ack; cat path/to/image.png'

# server
socat tcp-listen:9999\
  system:'IFS= read -r action; echo "ACK"; binary=$(cat -); echo "process image with action now..."'
```

which currently gets me

> Broken pipe

Is this type of duplex communication possible with `socat` at all (in best case without opening a new port)?

Have I overseen a simpler alternative?

I probably should have said, this is to be done in the most simplest/vanilla way possible, no further use of frameworks, no HTTP server overhead if possible. Shell is Bash, no ZSH avaiable. Vanilla Python can also be used.

Comment: this seems to be unnecessarily complicated. why not use a scripting language that natively supports sockets, rather than trying to forcibly do a client/server application in shell scripting, which was and is really not intended to do such things? Your life would be be easier with almost every alternative to shell scripting.

Comment: Or why not just a web server with CGI script to handle HTTP requests

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller. socat seemed to be the simplest solution and is available in my environment. I wasn't aware, socat is not supposed to do this, so better use e.g. Python sockets? Still curious, if this *could* be done with socat.

Comment: `cat -` waits for EOF, so for the client to terminate, then your `echo processing...` gets sent to a dead socket, hence the "broken pipe".

Comment: maybe you can coerce socat into doing that, but honestly, doing this using bash + socat + a million tricks seems so much harder than just writing a few lines of Python. Matter of fact, you could even write that server to work asynchronously and serve multiple clients at once… or if you're doing python anyways, you could work with an existing framework (e.g., flask) and just stop caring about the network and just publish the functionality you want to offer to your clients as REST endpoints at very low programming overhead. then your client could be any http client (e.g., `curl`) and you

Comment: wouldn't need to implement protocol state machines yourself (hinthint: dealing with multiple images in the same connection pretty becomes pretty interesting; knowing which reply belongs to which request, …)

Comment: FYI, zsh has builtin TCP support, both client and server, so if switching to that shell is an option, that may be simpler

Comment: (@StéphaneChazelas the CGI mechanism I think is not *that* common anymore, due to having-to-have-a-HTTP-Server-upfront, overhead of launching new processes, and complexity integrating with multi-request-by-default HTTP2 and HTTP3, but generally, letting scripts serve specific URLs is alive and well and what everyone does, as alluded to, in the shape of REST being used as RPC interface, and a REST server implementation into which you can just "hook" in the functions you want to "export" for basically any language but shells)

Comment: Very good ideas. I probably should have said, this is to be done in the most simplest/vanilla way possible, no further use of frameworks, no HTTP server overhead if possible. Shell is Bash, no ZSH avaiable. Vanilla Python can also be used.

Comment: Feel free to leave an answer to state socat is not suited for this type of activity, with possible hints for alternative here from the comment and I'll accept. Appreciate your quick comments

Comment: Note that only zsh can do `binary=$(cat)`, other shells can't store 0 bytes in their variables. Even in zsh, you'll still need to work around the fact that command substitution strips newline characters. `convert` can convert directly from stdin though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this type of duplex communication possible with socat at all (in best case without opening a new port)?

No; but that has nothing to do with `socat`. A TCP connection gets closed and then can't be used anymore. But your mechanism, and specifically `cat -` as Stéphane pointed out, rely on the connection being closed.

> Shell is Bash, no ZSH avaiable. Vanilla Python can also be used.

So, vanilla Python.

From  [Python documentation on included modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html), really only very slightly modified:

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

PORT = 8000

class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

with SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', PORT),
                        requestHandler = RequestHandler,
                        use_builtin_types = True) as server:
    server.register_introspection_functions()

    # Register a function under function.__name__.
    @server.register_function
    def convert(target_format: str, img: bytes):
        # do something with img instead of just returning it,
        # but you get the idea.
        return img

    @server.register_function
    def length(img: bytes):
        return len(img)


    server.serve_forever()
```

on the client end,

```
import xmlrpc.client

PORT = 8000

server_handle = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(f'http://localhost:{PORT:d}',
                                          use_builtin_types = True)

with open("inputimage.jpg", "rb") as infile:
    converted = server_handle.convert("image/png", infile.read())

with open("outputimage.png", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(converted)

# Print list of available methods
print(server_handle.system.listMethods())
```

Note that this is absolutely vanilla python. `xmlrpc.server` isn't any less included in standard python than say, `socket` or `math`.

---

We can stretch the vanilla concept a bit from there; `venv` is also part of Python's standard library. Soooo if all you *have* is standard Python:

```bash
python3 -m venv serverstuff
. serverstuff/bin/activate
pip install Flask
```

gives you a bit more comfort. You can then write a server that looks like [the quickstart example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def say_hello():
    return "helloo"


@app.route("/convert/<target_fmt>"):
def convert(target_fmt):
    print(target_fmt)
    try:
        infile = request.files["file"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return Response(response="", status=406)
    # convert it; infile is a Werkzeug.Filestorage
    # https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage
    data = infile.read()
    return Response(response=data, mimetype=f"image/{target_fmt}", status=200)
```

save to `server.py` and run as `python3 -m flask --app server run --port 8000`.

and the client is then super easy in shell scripting:

```bash
$ myfiletoupload=/home/mosaic/catpicture.jpg
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/convert/png -F "file=@${myfiletoupload}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that thorough answer! I'll study it tomorrow more in detail.

Comment: "But your mechanism, and specifically cat - as Stéphane pointed out, rely on the connection being closed." To clarify - and what I did take away from you: There is no easy way with socat to keep TCP connection open and use something different than `cat -`? E.g. socat server might use `fork,reuseaddr`. I am asking, as Python alternative causes a bit more effort, as needs to be installed in the mobile environment first (serveral hundred MB; socat already is installed with ~ 5MB).

Comment: Also - and I don't wan't to deviate too much from OP: Has your proposed solution advantages over say using [Python's socket API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)? Thanks for your effort, I'll mark this post as accepted.

Comment: re: easy way with socat: You missed my point: you need to implement a protocol. Something so that the server can know when your transfer is over. That is inherently a state machine. Implementing that certainly is possible, it's just awkward as hell in a language as badly suited for that as bash scripting. (as a matter of fact, dealing with things such as timeouts gracefully might actually be impossible, but I assume you're doing this to learn something, not for production)

Comment: Re: Python's socket API: you would still design a protocol, but this time you'd at least have a language that isn't as badly suited. The advantage of the solutions I presented is that the protocol design, the serialization and deserialization, the session handling is all done for you. And in the case of XMLRPC, as said, it's as built-in to python just as Python's `socket` API is. The overhead really shouldn't matter – you're comparing a bash script with Python :D none of that says "I'm going to achieve Gb/s throughputs or serve 1000s of requests per second".

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Socat:

What happens in your attempt is: After the first successful transfers the shell writes the file contents and terminates. Socat transfers the data to the server (and sends EOF using TCP halfclose). The server receives the data (and EOF), and sends the processing message. The client wants to write the processing message to the shell, but it has already terminated, thus "Broken pipe".

You want to know if there is a solution with Socat. Yes there is one, with almost a million tricks... It passed simple tests but might fail with realistic requirements.

The problem is that the shell has to send EOF but still has to be able to receive the message. I am not aware of a method to have a shell doing halfclose, so the trick is to use two shells that communicate the ACK condition outside of Socat using a pipe:

Client:

```
set +H; rm -f /tmp/pipe0; mkfifo /tmp/pipe0; 
socat -t 3600 \
  tcp:server:9999 \
  system:'echo "open"; cat /tmp/pipe0 >/dev/stderr; cat /path/to/imgfile'!!system:'IFS= read -r ack; echo $ack >/tmp/pipe0; cat >/dev/stderr'
```

Server:

```
socat -t 3600\
  tcp-listen:9999,reuseaddr \
  system:'IFS= read -r action; echo "ACK"; binary=$(cat -); echo "process image with action now..."'
```

Explanation:

"set +H" allows use of '!' in bash;

The pipe is first opened by the reader, therefore it must already exist.

"-t 3600" sets halfclose timeout in seconds and must be longer than the longest processing time;

the client opens two shells, one data source that nevertheless waits for ACK passed from other shell, it terminates after file transfer; the second shell gets all data from the server, especially the ACK after which it triggers the first shell, and finally just transfers server output to stderr.

Comment: Thanks! This actually explained best the error cause and is good material for educational purposes. I see now, this is hard work with socat...